# Scaling the X axis in numerical solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, scaling

I Have numerically solved these two coupled equations, but I need to know how to scale the x-axis in the plot by a factor of `(1/20)`

```
pde1 = -y1''[x] - (2*y1'[x])/x + ((y1[x])^3 + y2[x])y1[x] == 0;
 pde2 = y2''[x] + (2y2'[x])/x - (y1[x])^3 == 0;
  sol = NDSolve[ {pde1, pde2, y1[20] == 0.001, y2[20] == -0.001,
  y1'[0.001] == 0.001, y2'[0.001] == 0.001}, {y1, y2}, {x,0.001, 20}]
```

I have $x=(1/20)\tilde{x}$ I need to plot $y1(\tilde{x})$

Comment: Do you mean something like this?  `p1 = Plot[Evaluate[y1[x] /. sol], {x, 0.001, 20}, PlotRange -> All]; p2 = Plot[Evaluate[y1[x] /. sol], {x, 0.001, 20}, PlotRange -> All,    AspectRatio -> 20]; Grid[{{p1, p2}}]`  screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pte7l.png)  or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean in my equations I have $x=(1/20)\tilde{x}$ I need to plot $y1(\tilde{x})$

Answer (score 1):

> have x=(1/20)x~  I need to plot y1(x~)

Ok, so $\hat{x} = 20 x$, right? So why not plot $y_1(20 x)$? Like this (You need to also scale the range at same time)

```
pde1 = -y1''[x] - (2*y1'[x])/x + ((y1[x])^3 + y2[x]) y1[x] == 0;
pde2 = y2''[x] + (2 y2'[x])/x - (y1[x])^3 == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{pde1, pde2, y1[20] == 0.001, y2[20] == -0.001, 
   y1'[0.001] == 0.001, y2'[0.001] == 0.001}, {y1, y2}, {x, 0.001, 20}]
```

Now instead of

```
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[y1[x] /. sol], {x, 0.001, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Do

```
scale = 1/20;
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[y1[1/scale*x] /. sol], {x, scale*0.001, scale*20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If this is still not what you want, will delete this.